# Could the noveau driver cause a crash, even though Nvidia driver is active?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, crash

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with stock Gnome and Nvidia drivers:

```
└─( ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001184sv000019DAsd00004255bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

It would "appear" that the Nvidia driver 470 is the "active" one (is there any other way to confirm this?) and `noveau` is just installed but not active.

However, recently I'm experiencing UI freezes, and the only way I can get the system working again is via a remote SSH session and restarting LightDM:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

Looking into `syslog` I saw this immediately before the system froze:

```
Aug  6 22:53:54 gondor kernel: [12567.767668] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
Aug  6 22:53:54 gondor kernel: [12567.767696] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
Aug  6 22:53:54 gondor kernel: [12567.767715] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: channel 3: killed
Aug  6 22:53:54 gondor kernel: [12567.767724] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: engine 7: scheduled for recovery
Aug  6 22:53:54 gondor kernel: [12567.767729] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
Aug  6 22:53:54 gondor kernel: [12567.767746] nouveau 0000:02:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000004402000000 engine 1b [CE2] client 04
 [GPC0/T1_1] reason 08 [PITCH_MASK_VIOLATION] on channel -1 [0042211000 unknown]
```

which would indicate that something went wrong with `noveau` (but why? isn't it NOT supposed to be active?).

Now, the suggestion I got is to `blacklist` `noveau` in `/etc/modprobe.d`, but I fear that if I do that, I may completely bork the system.

So a couple of questions:

1. am I barking up the wrong tree?
2. either way, is it "safe" to blacklist `noveau`?

Thanks!

Comment: Try: hit the Super (Win) key and start typing `Additional Drivers`, a greenish icon will appear quite soon, click on it. If the Nouveau driver is selected, click on any other driver *(reasonable choice)* and let the system install it, if NOT selected, DO select it to install it, REBOOT, then deselect it again, reboot. See if the problem is gone. **(Idea: Make sure the Nouveau driver has been uninstalled)**

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the nouveau is part of the kernel. It only runs when no other driver is installed. I would recommend to make a clean uninstall of all drivers and install them again. That means uninstall everything with "nvidia" in the name, reboot into nouveau (so everthing is really gone and clean) and then install the nvidia driver of you choice. I would then reboot to be sure, but that might not be strictly necessary. Its quite easy to mess up a driver config by installing over existing drivers. Quite impossible to debug such a thing.

Comment: To the blacklisting. I would not do it as its unlikely the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. it turns out that the `Noveau` driver was indeed the one selected;
2. not sure how that came to pass: I certainly never deactivated the Nvidia driver;
3. the solution was to launch the `Additional Drivers` application, and select the "recommended" Nvidia driver (477 in my case)

That seems to have solved the issue, no more crashes since.